# How to import a module in Python from a different directory?

Tags: python, module, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I have the following directory structure:

```
- Milestone/
    - kk.py
- Repeat_Modules/
    - __init__.py
    - Automations.py
```

I want to import the Automations.py file into kk.py. How can I achieve this?

I've tried using the following import statement in kk.py:
`from Repeat_Modules import Automations`

But I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I also have tried this:

```
from ..Repeat_Modules import Automations
```

This time new Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo7aD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: No. i tried these answers. Im using Jupyter-Notebookb. its not working even in kk.py file.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment yet, thus I post this as an answer).

Maybe try something like

```
from ..Repeat_Modules import Automations
```

The double dot means, that the referenced module is in the parent directory of your current file. See [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#syntax-and-practical-examples_1) for a more detailed description. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3?rq=2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: I tried this too but couldn't get it work. I will try again. Could tell me what folder structure should be for this?